# How to connect PostgreSQL with Flutter?

Tags: database, postgresql, flutter, dart

I am trying to connect PostgreSQL database with Flutter applicationm but it doesn't work. I have using below code:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:postgres/postgres.dart';

var databaseConnection = PostgreSQLConnection("localhost", 5432, "postgres",
    username: "postgres", password: "postgresql");

initDatabaseConnection() async {
  await databaseConnection.open().then((value) {
    debugPrint("Database Connected!");
  });
}
```

The following message occurred. What I do? Give me some ideas.

> Performing hot restart...
> Syncing files to device SM J600G...
> Restarted application in 2,245ms.
> D/ViewRootImpl@3e2b9ebMainActivity: Relayout returned: old=[0,0]
> [720,1480] new=[0,0][720,1480] result=0x1 surface={valid=false 0}
> changed=false

Answer (score 0):

The Android operating system generates this notification when a layout action is carried out by your Flutter application. Typically, it's employed for view layout tracking and debugging. The notification contains details regarding the view's original and new dimensions as well as any modifications. Generally, this notice doesn't mean there's an issue with your program, so you may safely disregard it.